# MediaPlayer.start() sound execution delayed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've a strange problem with my app. 
Every time a button is clicked, I call a method to execute sound.

The code:

```
public static void executeSound(Context context) {
    if (isSoundEnabled(context)) {

        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.button_click);
        }

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Where `isSoundEnabled` function verified if user has sound enabled inside app.

Sound is not executed each time I tap button, but after I tap other buttons, and sounds are executed all together. 
So happen that I press three different buttons, and three sounds are executed only when I push a button for third time. How can I execute immediately the sound?
I have this problem on lollipop devices (the same code run perfectly on the same device but with kitkat)

Answer (score 0):

Change your execute method to this

```
    public static void executeSound(Context context) { 
           if (isSoundEnabled(context)) {

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, audioUriPath);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mp.release();
                    }
                });
    }
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work the same. 
I've add uri to audio like:
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context,Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ context.getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.button_click));
But i obtain an error on mediaPlayer: 
should have subtitle controller already set